# How to add spaces between the squares on a squarify plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to change the colors of the following graph to make it more specific to my case, but then I won't be able to see the different  sizes (many squares will be the same).
My program actually is :

```
squarify.plot(sizes=sizeTab, alpha=.8 )
                plt.axis('off')
                plt.title('Plottitle')
                plt.show()
```

is there a simple way to add a small spacing between the squares ?

[image: Figure example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The squarify graph [produces bars](https://github.com/laserson/squarify/blob/cca0f2325f7c23cacfeeec0897a2d78c64b2b015/squarify/__init__.py#L255). It would be hard to change the bar coordinates to allow for spacings, but giving the bars an edgecolor of the same color as the background (white) would have the same visual effect. So an option is to use

```
squarify.plot(sizes=sizeTab, alpha=.8, edgecolor="white", linewidth=2)
```

Change the linewidth to get more or less spacing.

Comment: That's a nice hack (and I've used it myself) but I note that the lines take some of the area from the blocks. Therefore, if you have some very small blocks, their area could be significantly affected.  Tiny blocks can end up being removed completely (i.e. entirely in your background color).  You can partially mitigate this by using an edgecolor with partial opacity and a small linewidth, e.g. `edgecolor='#00000044', linewidth=1`.